# NullPointerException with omnifaces CDNResourceHandler and myfaces 2.2.3

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I just moved my application from glassfish to TomEE, that includes moving from mojarra to myfaces. So far I had a few problems that I could fix, but I don't know how to tackle this one.

If I use CDNResourceHandler and the PROJECT_STAGE is Production I get a NullPointerException (it does work fine in Development mode)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.application.ResourceWrapper.getLibraryName(ResourceWrapper.java:94)
org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlScriptRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlScriptRenderer.java:259)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:674)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:554)
org.primefaces.renderkit.HeadRenderer.encodeBegin(HeadRenderer.java:84)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:596)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:526)
```

The Resource is  (org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CDNResourceHandler$1) https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css

The relevant parts of the code

faces-config.xml

```
<application>
    <resource-handler>org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.UnmappedResourceHandler</resource-handler>        
    <resource-handler>org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CDNResourceHandler</resource-handler>       

</application>
```

web.xml

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.CDN_RESOURCE_HANDLER_URLS</param-name>
    <param-value>bootstrap-cdn:bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js=//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js,
        bootstrap-cdn:font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css=//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css,
        bootstrap-cdn:bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css=//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css,
        cloudflare-cdn:meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css.....
```

Omnifaces 1.8.1 (also tried with 2.0-SNAPSHOT)
Myfaces 2.2.3

Comment: I just [fixed](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/e306bebfe819c4c34e78dc92eaa36e5fd237d234) it. Can you try [today's snapshot](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/2.0-SNAPSHOT/)? Sorry for any inconvenience caused by this. By the way, since 2.0, the CDN resource handler is *always* enabled, so it will run irrespective of development stage. By the way, which TomEE version are you using?

Comment: It worked with a little workaround, thank you!I'm on tomEE 1.7.0-SNAPSHOT, I replaced myfaces version with 2.2.4
The problem is that now there is a dependency with javax.enterprise.inject.spi.ProcessInjectionPoint, I can't load cdi-api-1.1 because i'm on CDI 1.0 and tomEE won't allow it.... What I did is just create that class in my project with that package and it works. Will omnifaces 2.0 require CDI 1.1?

Thanks

Comment: Very useful project BTW

Comment: I just read http://arjan-tijms.blogspot.nl/2014/04/what-should-be-minimum-dependency.html TomEE 1.7.0 has Open web beans 1.2.6 which does support CDI 1.1, but the CDI API is 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyFaces needed the library and resource name of the original resource so that it could mark the resource as "already rendered" (to prevent duplicate rendering). However, the `CDNResourceHandler` didn't pass the original resource back via `getWrapped()`.

This has been [fixed](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/e306bebfe819c4c34e78dc92eaa36e5fd237d234) and is available as per [current snapshot](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/2.0-SNAPSHOT/). In the future, when you encounter an exception when using OmniFaces, you'd better [report an issue](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues).